# What should be Lecture flow while studying electrostatics, capacitor and current electricity?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, soft-question, capacitance

Sometimes while studying electric field and charges I get some new terms, and while studying electric potential I get confused how the potential works. And then while studying current electricity, I wonder how to relate.

Comment: Perhaps start with full maxwell plus Lorentz force law and look up what terms are supposed to stem from system and what terms are supposed to stem from system's externals, I think there are only a handful of cases. Then know about the self energy problem. Then look at image for energy flux and field directions for an electric circuit. Then search for images depicting maxwell's laws. This is how I would do it if I started from scratch but still somehow knew what to look for xD

Comment: @Emil I will try that. But in my school textbook Lorentz force in given in moving charges and magnetism after current electricity. And flow in my textbook is like this 1.electric charges and field 2.electric potential and capacitance 3.current electricity 4. Moving charges and magnetism

Comment: And in one different book it's like 1. Current electricity 2. Electrostatics 3. Capacitors 4. Magnetism 5. Electromagnetic induction 6. Alternating current

Comment: Yeah but I got confused 100x over when I read my course book because there are tons of preconditions for each chapter to be valid that are sometimes not stated or understood by reader. Start with full picture and go backwards to the simplified models. Since it is an old theory you can have that luxury.

Comment: @Emil I will do that.

Comment: the integral forms feel more intuitive to me. I think net charge times velocity is, approximately at least, current. There are terms like charge diffusion and drift that are hard to find incorporated in Maxwells laws, I don't have good sources for that :-(

Comment: @TulsiPatil Electrostats -> Capacitors -> Current -> Magnetism -> EMI -> AC Best possible order, almost nothing is applied before being explained in an earlier chapter in this order.

Comment: @Emil That's alright. I will find. Thank you.

Comment: @aditya_stack yes. Thank you.